# compare two associative array and display the difference

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following Two array results coming from MySQL query result.

Array One (Orignal-Data):

```
Array
(
    [w_a] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cod] => CRR
                    [pr] => LL
                    [aid] => VM2254
                    [gender] => m
                    [title] => 
                )
        )

    [w_a_ml] => Array
        (
        )

    [w_a_ol] => Array
        (
        )

    [w_a_rl] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rol] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

Array Two (Changed-Data)

```
Array
(
    [w_a] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [cod] => CRR
                    [pr] => LL
                    [aid] => VM2254
                    [gender] => f
                    [title] => Mr
                )
        )

    [w_a_ml] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [wl] => 255
                    [care] => Sahan
                    [heigh] => 
                    [adam] => 
                    [instance] => Look 
                )
        )

    [w_a_ol] => Array
        (
        )

    [w_a_rl] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [rol] => 1
                )
        )
)
```

What I wan to achieve from the above two array is to compare and show the result in table format or Inside Form To each Field (Original and New-Change) like below.

```
    FiledsN     Original    New Change
    title       Empty       Mr
    Wl          Empty       255
    Care        Empty       Sahan
    gender        m         f
    instance    Empty       Look
```

I've tried making the array a single array using this function:

```
function array_single($arr) {
    if (!is_array($arr)) {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $res = array();
    foreach ($arr as $keys => $values) {
       if (is_array($values)) {
           $res = array_merge($res, array_single($values));
       } else {
           $res[$keys] = $values;
       }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

And then comparing using this:

```
function diff($new,$old) {
    $del=array_diff_assoc($old,$new);
    $add=array_diff_assoc($new,$old);
    return $diff=array("old"=>$del, "new"=>$add);
}
```

Comment: Ok so you have said what you want, now what investigation have you done and what did that lead to you trying

Comment: We have no problem helping but can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: ohhh, I have tried a lot...first I changed both to single Array then I try to compare but this [w_a_ml] => Array..i have got problem with...anyway...let me paste you some code just for...

Comment: that makes it single..array   function array_single($arr) { 
            if (!is_array($arr)) { 
                return FALSE; 
            } 
            $res = array(); 
            foreach ($arr as $keys => $values) { 
                if (is_array($values)) { 
                    $res = array_merge($res, array_single($values)); 
                } else { 
                    $res[$keys] = $values; 
                } 
            } 
            return $res; 
        }

Comment: then I am using this function....function diff($new,$old)
{
    $del=array_diff_assoc($old,$new);
    $add=array_diff_assoc($new,$old);
    return $diff=array("old"=>$del, "new"=>$add);
}