# get difference between arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have asked a bit similar question here,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343559/compare-two-associative-arrays?noredirect=1#comment26938095_18343559 or Here [compare two associative array and display the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339099/compare-two-associative-array-and-display-the-difference) But this is much improved and modified question to make it easy, as many Guru suggest me. Please No Negative. If I do any mistake just tell me and I will try to fix that, Please?

Here is the Question...
I am using php 5.3, and this array comes after passing many process from generated PDO MySQL query, and using the following function

```
function diff($new,$old)
{
    $del=array_diff_assoc($old,$new);
    $add=array_diff_assoc($new,$old);
    return $diff=array("old"=>$del, "news"=>$add);
}
```

The array looks like the following...

```
$aa= Array
(
    [old] => Array 
    (

                    [cod] => 
                    [gender] => m
                    [title] =>
    )
    [news] => Array 
    (
                    [cod] => 
                    [gender] => f
                    [title] => Mr
                    [wl] => 255
                    [heigh] => 
    )
)
```

I have tried the following code

$combine = array_merge_recursive($aa['old'], $aa['news']);

To produce the following Array..(This is exactly the result I want)

```
Array
(
    [gender] => Array 
    (
       [gender] => m
       [gender] => f           
    )
    [title] => Array 
    (
       [title] =>
       [title] => Mr           
    )
    [gender] => Array 
    (
       [gender] => m
       [gender] => f           
    )
    [wl] => Array 
    (
       [wl] =>
       [wl] => 255           
    )
)
```

But it seems I have some unwanted data included...

What it should do is, if any key exist in the [old] array and has value in [news] array with the same key then show it, if any key exit in [news] array with value show it But if there is any key in the [news] array and has no corresponding key in [old] array and has no value don't show it.

any idea, I will Appreciate....I just stack some how...

Comment: if key exists in old and has value in new, do you want it to show the old value or new value or both ?

Comment: I want to show both, so that I can use it for compare...old is blabla and new is blaba...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a logical error there. In an array with key-value pairs, there can't be two different values for the same key:

```
[gender] => Array 
    (
       [gender] => m
       [gender] => f
    )
```

In the above resulting array, `gender` is repeated twice. What would `$array['gender']['gender']` return?

Assuming you want an array instead:

```
[gender] => Array 
    (
       m,
       f
    )
```

You can just iterate over both arrays and add the corresponding values. Here's an example that assumes an empty value to be `null`:

```
$final = array(); // final array
$old;
$new;

foreach ($old as $k => $v) {
    $final[$k] = array($v, null);
}

foreach ($new as $k => $v) {
    if (array_key_exists($k, $final) {
        $final[$k][1] = $v;
    } else {
        $final[$k] = array(null, $v);
    }
}
```

The above code will print something along the lines of:

```
Array
(
    [gender] => Array 
    (
       m, f           
    )
    [title] => Array 
    (
       null, Mr           
    )
    [gender] => Array 
    (
       m, f           
    )
    [wl] => Array 
    (
       null, 255           
    )
)
```

which is the closest possible thing to your resulting array.

Comment: I have passed the arrays like this,  $final = array(); // final array
  $old = $result['old'];
  $new = $result['new']; am I correct?

Comment: @Mr.Jefffrey Thanks for your help and showing me different direction to think, Your Direction works For me and, I accept it As Answer. Thanks Once again.